# turbostat doesn't show only desired columns with --show option

Tags: linux, cpu, utilities

I'm using tubostat in Manjaro 18.1.5:

```
$ pacman -Qs turbostat
local/turbostat 5.4-3 (linux-tools)
```

the man page says:

```
--show  column  show  only  the  specified built-in columns.  May be invoked multiple times, or with a comma-separated list of column names.  Use "--show
       sysfs" to show the sysfs statistics columns as a group.
...
...
--list display column header names available for use by --show and --hide, then exit.
```

When I display columns I can use:

```
$ sudo turbostat --list
usec,Time_Of_Day_Seconds,Core,CPU,APIC,X2APIC,Avg_MHz,Busy%,Bzy_MHz,TSC_MHz,IRQ,SMI,POLL,C1,C1E,C3,C6,C7s,C8,C9,C10,POLL%,C1%,C1E%,C3%,C6%,C7s%,C8%,C9%,C10%,CPU%c1,CPU%c3,CPU%c6,CPU%c7,CoreTmp,PkgTmp,GFX%rc6,GFXMHz,Pkg%pc2,Pkg%pc3,Pkg%pc6,Pkg%pc7,Pkg%pc8,Pkg%pc9,Pk%pc10,PkgWatt,CorWatt,GFXWatt
```

I can see various C levels I can use for columns, so if I want to see only C1 and C2, I run the following command:

```
$ sudo turbostat --show C1,C2
Invalid counter name: C1
```

**Why I'm I getting *invalid counter name: C1*?**

When I try to leave out column C1 with `--hide` option, it works as expected:

```
$ sudo turbostat --hide C1,C2
...
...
Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IRQ SMI POLL    C1E C3 ...
...
```

If I use `sysfs` to refer to all C states, it again works as expected:

```
$ sudo turbostat --show sysfs
...
POLL    C1  C1E C3  C6  C7s C8  C9  C10 ...
...
```

I've also tried to list different columns (POLL, C7, C1%, ...) with `--show` option, but the result was always the same as in the example above with C1 and C2 columns.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to figure out why and this is my best attempt on an answer. If I'm wrong, please say so.

The source code of my current version of turbostat could be found [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c?h=v4.19.96).

If I run turbostat with `--show` option, [function `bic_lookup`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c?h=v4.19.96#n566) gets called. If I run turbostat with C level names like this: `--show C1,C3` etc., I always end up with [this error](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c?h=v4.19.96#n590).

To me, it seems that "the problem" is on [this line](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c?h=v4.19.96#n583), because [this struct](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c?h=v4.19.96#n394) does not have the C1, C3 etc. names I'm using as parameters with `--show` option. It also says in [the comment](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c?h=v4.19.96#n390):

```
1. built-in only, the sysfs counters are not here -- we learn of those at run-time
```

Those C levels I'm using are these sysfs counters, turbostat learns about them only at run-time, but [the loop in bic_lookup function](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c?h=v4.19.96#n582) works with only these hard-coded column names. If I use one of the names directly written in `bic` struct, turbostat actually shows me only such a column(s) as expected.

It seems that the only option is to use `--show sysfs`, which prints the columns I want.

All in all, the man page seems a bit confusing when it says:

```
--list display column header names available for use by --show and --hide, then exit.
```

because when `--list` gets executed, even column names such as C1, C3 are shown.

(Please note that I'm not a programmer, so my terminology might be confusing or wrong. Feel free to edit my comment as necessary.)